# How to check two excels in a validation?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I'm trying to check two excels in a validation using excel tag of PAF while automation .Is it possible to validate two excels at the same time in pace automation framework?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet is given below you can use for referral:

```
<activity id="Validations">

    <excel excelPath="./excel1.xlsx" sheetName="Sheet4" resultsetVar="RSVar1" primaryKey="FirstName"></excel>

    <excel excelPath="./excel2.xlsx" sheetName="Sheet5" resultsetVar="RSVar2" primaryKey="FirstName"></excel>

           <validation valGroupIds="verify2ExcelsEquals" desc="TAG- validation; ATTRIBUTES- valGroupIds;" expResult="Verified the Excel files excel1 and excel2" ></validation>

</activity>

<valGroup groupId="verify2ExcelsEquals">

          <validate resultsetVar1="RSVar1" resultsetVar2="RSVar2" condition="equals" passMsg="VERIFIED THE EXCEL FILES excel1 and excel2 ARE EQUAL" failMsg="FAILED EXCEL FILES ARE NOT EQUAL"></validate>

</valGroup>
```